# JQuery + WCF + HTTP 404 Error

Tags: jquery, wcf

HI All,
I've searched high and low and finally decided to post a query here.

I'm writing a very basic HTML page from which I'm trying to call a WCF service using jQuery and parse it using JSON.

Service:

IMyDemo.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyDemo
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         Employee DoWork();


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         Employee GetEmp(int age, string name);


    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int EmpSalary { get; set; }

    }
```

MyDemo.svc.cs

```
 public Employee DoWork()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here 
            Employee obj = new Employee() { EmpSalary = 12, EmpName = "SomeName" };
            return obj;
        }

 public Employee GetEmp(int age, string name)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();

            if (age > 0)
                emp.EmpSalary = 12 + age;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                emp.EmpName = "Server" + name;

            return emp;
        }
```

WEb.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EmployeesBehavior" name="MySample.MyDemo">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MySample.IMyDemo" behaviorConfiguration="EmployeesBehavior"/>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EmployeesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EmployeesBehavior">
          <webHttp/>         
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

MyDemo.htm

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Scripts/json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //create a global javascript object for the AJAX defaults.
        debugger;
var ajaxDefaults = {};

ajaxDefaults.base = { 
    type: "POST", 
    timeout : 1000,

    dataFilter: function (data) { 
        //see http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/ 
        data = JSON.parse(data); //use the JSON2 library if you aren’t using FF3+, IE8, Safari 3/Google Chrome 
        return data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data; 
    },

    error: function (xhr) { 
        //see 
        if (!xhr) return; 
        if (xhr.responseText) { 
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
            //console.log works in FF + Firebug only, replace this code 
            if (response)    alert(response); 
            else alert("Unknown server error"); 
        } 
    } 
};

ajaxDefaults.json = $.extend(ajaxDefaults.base, { 
    //see http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json" 
});

var ops = {
    baseUrl: "/MyService/MySample/MyDemo.svc/",

    doWork: function () { 
        //see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ 
        var ajaxOptions = $.extend(ajaxDefaults.json, {

            url: ops.baseUrl + "DoWork", 
            data: "{}",

            success: function (msg) { 
                console.log("success"); 
                console.log(typeof msg); 
                if (typeof msg !== "undefined") { 
                    console.log(msg); 
                } 
            } 
        });

        $.ajax(ajaxOptions); 
        return false; 
    },
    getEmp: function () { 
        var ajaxOpts = $.extend(ajaxDefaults.json, {

            url: ops.baseUrl + "GetEmp", 
            data: JSON.stringify({ age: 12, name: "NameName" }),

            success: function (msg) { 
                $("span#lbl").html("age: " + msg.Age + "name:" + msg.Name); 
            } 
        });

        $.ajax(ajaxOpts); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<span id="lbl">abc</span> 
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="GetEmployee" id="btnGetEmployee" onclick="javascript:ops.getEmp();" /> 
</body>
```

I'm just not able to get this running.
When I debug, I see the error being returned from the call is 
"

## Server Error in '/jQuerySample' Application.

```
        <h2> <i>HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.</i> </h2></span>
```

"

Looks like I'm missing something basic here.
My sample is based on  [this](http://meondotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/consuming-a-json-wcf-service-with-jquery/)

I've been trying to fix the code for sometime now so I'd like you to take a look and see if you can figure out what is it that I'm doing wrong here.

I'm able to see that the service is created when I browse the service in IE.
I've also tried changing the setting as mentioned  [here](http://www.codegain.com/tips/wcf/general/http-404-not-found-problem-when-deploying-wcf-in-iis-7-0.aspx)

Appreciate your help.
I'm gonna blog about this as soon as the issue is resolved for the benefit of other devs
Thanks
-Soni

Comment: This needs to go on http://stackoverflow.com/ (different sites, different purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the first time I tried jQuery/JSON. I thought I could get it working with some samples. But as it turns out, its never that easy to get some code running!

so i did console.log and turned out my msg object was like this
[
Object
Comment: "My Comment"
EvalId: "0"
Submitter: "SS"
Timesent: "/Date(1298299273798+0530)/"

so instead of msg.EvalId all i had to do was 
msg[0].EvalId.toString()

Definitely the dreaded "undefined" error was something to crack!!

I will definitely be posting on my blog on this.. but after days of banging my head.. turns out I need to go through some basics first!!

But in this process, learnt some good stuff on fiddler, firebug,  Cross-site scripting  ..

I'm impressed with jQuery/JSON and planning to deep dive now!!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following code -

Change your web.config to include the following-

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then, decorate your MyDemo.svc.cs with the following attribute

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Comment: ok .. so i got it up and running .. my fault!! <br> but now I'm stuck at the JSON end ..  <br> my code looks like this <br> success: function (msg) { <br>
                    debugger; <br>
                    alert(msg.toString);<br>
                    $("span#lbl").html("empID: " + msg.EvalId + "name:" + msg.Submitter); <br>
                }<br> i get an undefined value for both EvalID and Submitter. <br> I tried using JSON2 as well.. went through some queries where they asked to remove DivX add on.. but it still didnt work.. any ideas?

Comment: Would of really helped if you posted how you got it, 'up and running.' For others' future reference.